# The best way for inserting multiple objects into array

Tags: javascript, mapreduce

I have a transformer helper function. It reduces over the array and transform key/value pairs. At the end of the loop there is the key 'EXAMPLE1' exists and I should insert two objects after the first and the second array(result) items. Right now, it works as expected, but I have concerns - is it a good approach for using splice inside reduce in my case?

````
 const commonData = Object.entries(settings).reduce((result, [currentKey, currentValue]) => {
        if (currentKey === SETTINGS_FIELDS.EXAMPLE1) {
            const type = {
                key: myKey,
                value: myValue,
            }
            const code = {
                key: myKey,
                value: myValue,
            }

            const insertedData = result.splice(2, 0, type, code)

            return [...result, ...insertedData]
        }



        return result.concat({ key: transformToUpperCase(currentKey), value: currentValue })
    }, [])

    return [...commonData]
}
```
````

Comment: I don't understand why you're using reduce here. Do you just want to insert these two key/value pairs into the array? Then just use `splice()` on the array directly. Do you want to do it only if the `settings` object contained the key `EXAMPLE1`? Then do it. What do you mean by "at the end of the loop"?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you were trying to follow the best practices on not mutating data but this is an overkill:

- when processing data locally in a function there's no need to clone the intermediate data
- no need to clone the array in `return`, it's already a temporary cloned array
- `reduce` is the wrong choice here - at least if you keep its needless duplication of the resultant array in each step - the task is a simple transformation of each element so `map()` seems a better choice + an additional splice on the special key
- `insertedData` is always an empty array so no need for `[...result, ...insertedData]`
- for consistency, if you use `splice` and `concat` then go all the way and use `concat` instead of array spread as well or switch to array spread instead of concat.

Simplified code using `map()`:

```
function foo() {

  const commonData = Object.entries(settings).map(([key, value]) => ({
    key: transformToUpperCase(key),
    value,
  }));

  if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(settings, SETTINGS_FIELDS.EXAMPLE1)) {
    commonData.splice(2, 0, {
      key: myKey,
      value: myValue,
    }, {
      key: myKey,
      value: myValue,
    });
  }

  return commonData;
}
```

If you don't override prototype of `settings` or objects in general the key check can be simplified further: `if (SETTINGS_FIELDS.EXAMPLE1 in settings)`